# How do I give trust to a self-signed certificate for Zypper?

Tags: repository, certificates, suse, zypper

We're trying to set up a repository for SuSE Linux-based devices. We are authenticating the repository with a CA that contains, at its root, a self-signed certificate. When trying to retrieve updates from the repository, we get this message:

```
Connecting to server|10.0.1.15|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify server's certificate, issued by `/CN=IntermediateCA_server_1/O=Company/OU=MACOSX OpenDirectory Intermediate CA/emailAddress=it@company.com':
Self-signed certificate encountered.
```

The update then fails due to lack of trust.

Is there a way to install the self-signed certificate on the devices so that zypper finds it and knows to trust it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if above OpenSuSE 13 you could copy your root CA into `/etc/pki/trust/anchors/`
and then run the

```
  update-ca-certificates
```

command to import it.

Comment: so sad when you don't have 'update-ca-certificates' package and cannot install it due to "cannot verify server's certificate"

Comment: For SLE11 it's `/etc/ssl/certs` and `c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs`. Taken from: https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?9465-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate